# Need to add mutiple values from a list within a list (IndexError: list index out of range)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add together data from multiple 'patients' i need to be able to output the average required protein, carbs, fats and kilojoules for the group of patients

I'm still learning python and ive been reading through tons of other questions but nothing seems to work

i get the error on line 29 with sum_f however i think there is probably issues with sum_p and sum_f as well

I was previously getting int object is not subscriptable but I think I've fixed that

```
patient_input = int(input("Enter number of patients:"))
a = 1
patient_data=[]
if patient_input > 0:
    while a <= patient_input :
        a_str = str(a)
        print ("Patient " + (a_str))
        protein = int(input("Amount of protein (g) required:"))
        while protein <= 0:
            print ("Please enter a nonnegative number" )
        carbohydrates = int(input("Amount of carbohydrates (g) required:"))
        while carbohydrates <= 0:
            print ("Please enter a nonnegative number" )
        fat= int(input("Amount of fat (g) required:"))
        while fat <= 0:
            print ("Please enter a nonnegative number" )
        kilojules = 4.18 * (4*protein + 4*carbohydrates + 9.30*fat)
        a_str = [protein, carbohydrates, fat, kilojules]
        patient_data.append(a_str)
        a = a + 1
    print(patient_data)
```

^this seems to be fine ive been fixing the errors in it over the last couple hours

```
    b = int((patient_input) + 1)
    sum_p = sum(int(i)for i in patient_data [0][0:b])
    average_p =(int(b))*(sum_p)
    sum_c = sum(int(i)for i in patient_data [1][0:b]) 
    average_c = str((b)*(sum_c))
    sum_f = sum(int(i)for i in patient_data [2][0:b]) 
    average_f = str((b)*(sum_f))
    sum_k = sum(int(i)for i in patient_data [3][0:b]) 
    average_k = str((b)*(sum_k))
    print ("Averages:")
    print ("Protein (g):" (average_p))
    print ("Carbohydrates (g):" (average_c))
    print ("Fats (g):" (average_f))
    print ("Kilojules (kJ):" (average_k))
```

when sum_p adds up it seems to be adding the patient's protein, carbs, fats and kilojules when i need it to add the protein of the patients together so i can divide by the number of patients to get the average

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure you have the indices ordered wrong here:

`sum_p = sum(int(i)for i in patient_data [0][0:b])`

The first `[0]` tells you to use the first patient, then `[0:b]` is going through the different measurements for that patient.  Try switching them:

`sum_p = sum(int(i)for i in patient_data[0:b][0])`

Note: since you had more patients than you do measurements for each patient, `[0:b]` will go beyond all the measurements for the current patient and give the index out of range error.